# How to get factor of integer number using command-line?

Tags: command-line

I want to get **prime factor of some integer numbers** by using **command-line.**

Example:

An Integer number `786` has (prime) factors: 
`2`, `3` and  `131`

Other example for `1234567890` is : 
`2`, `3` (two times), `5`, `3607` and `3803`.

**How do I get such above result using simple command?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is **`factor`** command available as follows:

```
NAME
       factor - factor numbers

SYNOPSIS
       factor [NUMBER]...

DESCRIPTION
       Print  the  prime  factors  of  each specified integer NUMBER.  If none are specified on the command line, read them from
       standard input.
```

**Example:**

```
$ factor 786
786: 2 3 131

$ factor 1234567890
1234567890: 2 3 3 5 3607 3803
```

Visit : [`man factor`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/factor.1.html).